# How to refactor Rails form component

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to partialize duplicated `form_for` in `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`.
I think there are two ways to do this:

1. Put entire `form_for` codes into a partial.
2. Put only field elements into a partial.

Which do you choose? Is this matter of taste?
I'd like to know if there are any practical reasons for your choice.
If you have the third way, it's also welcome.

**The first way:**

```
 <%= render 'form', object: @user, button_name: "Create my account" %>
```

and the partial (`_form.html.erb`) is:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit button_name %>
<% end %>
```

Or,

**The second way:**

```
 <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
   <%= f.submit "Create my account" %>
 <% end %>
```

and the partial (`_fields.html.erb`) is:

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Examples are  simplyfied, you have more fields and labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way. Readability is important over here. Second way is really bad.

In case you need to check if it's a new record in your partial, you can add this:

```
<% if @user.new_record? %>
  ... your code here ...
<% end %>
```